# Pareto distribution: R vs Python - different results

Tags: python, r, scipy, data-science

I'm trying to replicate R's fitdist() results (reference, cannot modify R code) in Python using `scipy.stats`. The results are totally different. Does anyone know why? How can I replicate R's results in Python?

```
data = [2457.145, 1399.034, 20000.0, 476743.9, 24059.6, 28862.8]
```

**R code:**

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(actuar)

fitdist(data, 'pareto', "mle")$estimate
```

**R results:**

```
       shape        scale 
    0.760164 10066.274196
```

**Python code**

```
st.pareto.fit(data, floc=0, scale=1)
```

**Python results**

```
(0.4019785013487883, 0, 1399.0339889072732)
```

Comment: Can you show which R libraries you are using for the implementation of the Pareto distribution and  `fitdist`?

Comment: I use ```actuar``` and ```fitdistrplus```  libraries

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser PDFs seems to be a little bit different... But Is it possible to get the same PDF in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discrepancy is mainly due to the differing pdfs.

## Python

In python `st.pareto.fit()` uses a Pareto distribution defined via this pdf:

[image]

```
import scipy.stats as st
data = [2457.145, 1399.034, 20000.0, 476743.9, 24059.6, 28862.8]
print(st.pareto.fit(data, floc = 0, scale = 1))

# (0.4019785013487883, 0, 1399.0339889072732)
```

## R

Whereas your R code is using a Pareto with this pdf:

[image]

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(actuar)
data <- c(2457.145, 1399.034, 20000.0, 476743.9, 24059.6, 28862.8)
fitdist(data, 'pareto', "mle")$estimate

#    shape        scale 
#    0.760164 10066.274196
```

## Make R Mirror Python

To get R to use the same distribution as `st.pareto.fit()` use `actuar::dpareto1()`:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(actuar)
data <- c(2457.145, 1399.034, 20000.0, 476743.9, 24059.6, 28862.8)
fitdist(data, 'pareto1', "mle")$estimate

#     shape          min 
#   0.4028921 1399.0284977
```

## Make Python Mirror R

And here is one approach to approximate your R code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def dpareto(x, shape, scale):
    return shape * scale**shape / (x + scale)**(shape + 1)

def negloglik(x):
    data = [2457.145, 1399.034, 20000.0, 476743.9, 24059.6, 28862.8]
    return -np.sum([np.log(dpareto(i, x[0], x[1])) for i in data])

res = minimize(negloglik, (1, 1), method='Nelder-Mead', tol=2.220446e-16)
print(res.x)

# [7.60082820e-01 1.00691719e+04]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it a universal approach? Will python approach work for other distributions in case of different pdfs (own ```pdf```,  ```negloglik()``` and ```minimize(negloglik,...)```)?

Comment: It is a basic implementation of the MLE approach and would work for many distributions but not all. For example, there may be constraints on the support of the distribution that the code does not enforce.